# Knockoutjs: Remove/add element from array nested in viewmodel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to remove and add an element from an array which is nested in a ko.observable object. I'm using the ko.mapping utility to map json data to my viewmodel. Inside the json data i have an array and it is this array that i want to remove and add an element from.

The add and remove functions are call from HTML bindings.

See my current code for doing this. It is not elegant at all, i know that, that is why i'm asking for help. How do i do see smarter?

```
function BaseViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.newItem = null;
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

    self.getNewItem = function () {
        return self.newCleanItem(self.newItem);
    }

    self.read = function (search, callback) {
        self.baseService.read(search, callback);
    }

    self.readCallback = function (data) {
        if (self.newItem == null)
            self.newItem = data;
        self.selectedItem(data);
        showInputContainer();
    }

    self.addLog = function () {
        var item = new self.getNewItem();
        var newItem = item.tLogs[0];
        var currentSelectedItem = ko.mapping.toJS(self.selectedItem);
        currentSelectedItem.tLogs.push(newItem);
        self.selectedItem(currentSelectedItem);
        showInputContainer(activeTab);
    };

    self.removeLog = function (item) {
        var currentSelectedItem = ko.mapping.toJS(self.selectedItem);
        currentSelectedItem.tLogs.pop(item);
        vm.selectedItem(currentSelectedItem);
        showInputContainer();
    }

    self.newCleanItem = function (data) {
        for (var d in data) {
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(data[d]) === '[object Array]') {
                var array = data[d];
                for (var item in array) {
                    if (framework.baseFunctions().isNumeric(item)) {
                        for (var i in array[item]) {
                            array[i] = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
                data[d] = array;
            }
            else {
                data[d] = "";
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

My jsondata could look that this:

```
jsondata = {
    caseName: "test",
    caseDescription: "This is a test",
    tLogs: [
        {
            name: "log1",
            date: "2013-03-19"
        },
        {
            name: "log2",
            date: "2013-02-02"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm missing a few points here... where is the *self* variable initialized? Did you mean *this*? And even in that case, where do you set the *self.newItem* property used in *self.getNewItem*? Also, are you calling the add and remove method from code or directly from bindings?

Comment: Grim, i added the code you are asking for and the add and remove function are called from html binding.